# flask.session is losing data from one view to another

Tags: python, flask

I'm coding a very simple flask web app so that the testers from the place where I'm working could test my deep learning model without download the project.
It has a view which receive a pdf file and a string in a forms (the input for the deep learning model) and another view which shows another string (the output for the deep learning model).
I'm trying to use the `flask.session` object to pick the data from the first view and pass it to the second view and after that I store it in the `flask.g` object so that I can display it in a Jinja template.
My problem is that the `flask.session` object is losing the data from one view to another. How to avoid that?
I'm not very worried with security issues because only the testers from my job will have access to the web app.
And sorry if the question is very stupid, I'm a complete newbie.

I know there is probably best ways to do that but I want to keep it as simple as possible because I'm only doing that to test the deep learning model easily.

```py
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

bp = Blueprint('book', __name__, url_prefix='/book')

@bp.route('/initialpage', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def initialpage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_file = request.form['book']
        parsed = parser.from_file(book_file)
        book = parsed["content"]

        question = request.form['question']
        error = None

        if not book:
            error = 'Book is required.'
        elif not question:
            error = 'Question is required.'

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['book'] = book
            session['question'] = question
            print(session['question'])
            return redirect(url_for('book.finalpage'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('book/initialpage.html')


@bp.route('/finalpage')
def finalpage():
    book_body = session.get('book')
    book_question = session.get('question')

    if book_body is None:
        g.book = None
    elif book_question is None:
        g.question = None
    else:
        g.book = book_body
        g.question = book_question

    return render_template('book/finalpage.html')
```

The data stored in `session['book']` and `session['question']` is lost when passing from the `'/initialpage'` to the `'/finalpage'` .

Comment: Are you sure that error is None?

Comment: I think so because ```session['book']``` and ```session['question']``` are with the data in the ```'/initialpage' ``` view (I saw that with the ```print(session['question'])``` line inside the ```if error is None``` statement). But that data is being lost in the ```'/finalpage' ``` view .

Comment: I am too not able to do this. I had posted a question also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206878/flask-session-is-not-staying-the-same-within-two-api-calls , but didn't get any proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to solve this problem!
In my case I think the problem was that my data was too big to be passed by flask.session. I found that most browsers don't support a session cookie larger than ~4000 bytes and my data is like ~10 MB.
So my idea was to create a database to store the data and pass only an id (which allows to find the data in the database) by flask.session.
As database I used Python SQLite3. 
The functions to connect to the database and to initialize it were coded in a separated file.
The code became the following:

````
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

from flaskr.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('book', __name__, url_prefix='/book')

@bp.route('/initialpage', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def initialpage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_file = request.form['book']
        parsed = parser.from_file(book_file)
        book = parsed["content"]
        question = request.form['question']
        db = get_db()
        error = None

        if not book:
            error = 'Book is required.'
        elif not question:
            error = 'Question is required.'

        if error is None:
            if db.execute('SELECT book, question FROM bq').fetchone() is None:
                db.execute('INSERT INTO bq (book, question) VALUES (?, ?)',(book, question))
                db.commit()

            bq = db.execute('SELECT * FROM bq WHERE (book, question) = (?, ?)',(book, question)).fetchone()
            session.clear()
            session['bq_id'] = bq['id']
            print(bq['id'])
            return redirect(url_for('book.finalpage'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('book/initialpage.html')


@bp.route('/finalpage')
def finalpage():
    bq_id = session.get('bq_id')
    print(bq_id)

    if bq_id is None:
        g.bq = None
    else:
        g.bq = get_db().execute('SELECT * FROM bq WHERE id = ?', (bq_id,)).fetchone()

    return render_template('book/finalpage.html')```
````